# Call Shortcode Attribute Value within another function

Tags: regex, customization

Please anyone with an idea of how I can extract some values of this shortcode attributes and use it within another function.

How the code looks like:

```
function myVal($attr, $content = null) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'var1'  => '',
    'var2'  => '',
    'var3'  => '',
    'var4'  => '',
    'var5'  => '',
  ), $attr));

  return $var1.' '.$var3.' '.$var5;

  //Value to display outside the wordpress shortcode.
  global $outvalue;
  $outvalue = $val2.' '.$val4;
```

}

Then I will like to call the $outvalue variable within another function.

```
function outval() {
  global $outvalue;
  echo $outvalue;
}
```

The issue is that the $outvalue is not displaying anything, please guys help I don't know what am doing wrong, I also learnt I can use `get_shortcode_regex()`but I don't know how to use it to call the `$outvalue;`.Please will appreciate step by step answer guide. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: You return before you add the values to the `$outvalue`, so this part of the code is never reached.

Second: You have typos, when adding the values to `$outvalue`.

This function works for me:

```
function myVal($attr, $content = null) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'var1'  => '',
    'var2'  => '',
    'var3'  => '',
    'var4'  => '',
    'var5'  => '',
  ), $attr));

  //Value to display outside the wordpress shortcode.
  global $outvalue;
  $outvalue = $var2.' '.$var4;

  return $var1.' '.$var3.' '.$var5;

}
```

Bear in mind, when those values are actually assigned to `$outvalue`. This happens after in `the_content()`, because the shortcode is parsed in the `the_content`-filter.

So, if you would call `outval()` in the header.php, you wouldn't get any information, because your shortcode function has not run yet. If you would call it in the footer.php, the values would be assigned.

Comment: Thanks much the mistake am doing is the arrangement, everything is now working

Comment: happy to hear :)